# The adverb "впустую" is made up of "в" + "пустую" + "what feminine noun"?

Tags: выражения

> Пока ты проводишь свое драгоценное время **впустую** и занимаешься бесполезными делами, ...

The accusative feminine construction "в + пустую" leads me to think that some feminine noun is theoretically omitted at the end.

> впустую: в + пустую + ???
>
> spend time **to empty/vain + ???**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a limited group of adverbs which for some reason (perhaps historical) assume Accusative inflection of words in feminine gender

> вслеп**у**ю (стрелять)
>   вчист**у**ю (проиграть)
>   втёмную (действовать)
>   всух**у**ю (выиграть)
>   вничь**ю** (сыграть)
>   вхолост**у**ю (сделать что-л.)
>   напропал**у**ю (гулять)
>   зачаст**у**ю (случаться)
>   вкрут**у**ю (сварить яйца)
>   врассыпн**у**ю (бежать)
>   врукоп**а**шную (ходить)
>   вплотн**у**ю (стоять)
>   напрям**у**ю (говорить)
>   втих**у**ю (сделать что-л.)
>   ни в как**у**ю (не хотеть)
>   вжив**у**ю (увидеть)  <sup>*could be a later creation in the familiar pattern*</sup>
>   влёгкую (обыграть) <sup>*modern colloquial*</sup>
>   втуп**у**ю (действовать) <sup>*modern slang*</sup>

And you're probably correct in assuming the existence of a noun which would follow them in their ancient form, but i'm unaware of what these noun or nouns might have been.

Comment: Also: `внаглую`, `на боковую`, `на мировую`, `на попятную`, `в открытую`. And I'm not sure about: `воочию`.

Comment: *воочию* is dual locative, compare modern Russian *на глазах*

Comment: with `на боковую` i can think of the word `сторону` as the omitted object

Answer (score 3):

Despite the word `впустую` looks like you described, its meaning is very similar if not the same as for words: `зря`, `напрасно`.

And you're right, if there are two words `в пустую`, they are typically followed by an accusative feminine noun.

And I'm not aware how `впустую` is related to `в пустую`, except for similar looking. I'd not be surprised if there is no relationship at all.

Answer (score 3):

Don't consider this information to be an answer. There is an explanation in what way the process might go. Briefly speaking, there was a noun, several nouns to be precise before the adverb was formed.It was formed from a noun phrase with a preposition. Some phrases remained till now (see P.S.)

Особый интерес представляют наречия, соотносительные с предложно-падежными формами прилагательных: въмалѣ, съмо- лоду, издавьна, помногу, помалу и т. п. Хотя такая их соотносительность с предложно-падежными формами прилагательных как будто бы очевидна, объяснить их происхождение непосредственно из таких форм нельзя, так как русскому языку сочетания прилагательных с предлогами несвойственны. Существуют разные объяснения происхождения данных наречий, одно из которых заключается в том, что они возникли в результате **„свертывания" атрибутивно-именных словосочетаний с последующей адвербиализацией прилагательного** (этот процесс можно назвать лексико-семантической конденсацией). Дело заключается в том, что в древнерусском языке существовали **атрибутивно-именные сочетания, выступавшие в обстоятельственной функции**, которые были соотносительны с наречиями. Такая соотносительность присуща временным и пространственным наречиям, что связано с выражением временной и пространственной характеристики действия определительными словосочетаниями, в состав которых входили **существительные с общим временным или пространственным значением**, выступающие в качестве опорных слов таких сочетаний; таковыми во временных обстоятельственных конструкциях были слова **врем*, лѣто, часъ, дьнь**, а в пространственных — **страна (сторона), путь**. Обобщенное лексическое значение опорного существительного в таких сочетаниях обусловливало то, что основную семантическую нагрузку получало прилагательное, а не существительное, которое вследствие этого могло опускаться. Опущение определяемого имени облегчалось устойчивым характером таких словосочетаний, а их обстоятельственная функция способствовала переходу прилагательного в наречие. Так, например, из **по малѣ времени, часѣ развилось наречие помалѣ; из по мнозѣ лѣтѣ — помнозѣ; из не въ дълзѣ времени — невъдълзѣ; из из давьна времени — издавьна; из о десьную его страну — одеськую; из отъ далеча пути — отъдалеча**. Такое объяснение было предложено Е. И. Янович в книге „Наречие в истории русского языка"

PS So the noun was "**сторона**", there are still some hints or remnants in our language and in English as well. We can say

> Он изменился (как?) **в лучшую сторону**.
>
> He smiled **in a friendly way**.

Comment: hi, in the context of which adverb in your opinion the noun was **сторона**?

Comment: Впустую --в сторону (в направлении ) пустоты "Сторона " была обобщенным понятием для пространства, впоследствии утраченным, наряду с "путем". Я про вопрос. Но эти слова приемлемы и для других наречий.

Comment: as far as i gathered from the text, **сторона** is mentioned as just one example of such noun, i doesn't take it to mean that it was specifically these two  (+  **путь**) nouns which were used with all spatial adverbs, and **в пустую сторону** doesn't sound very logical to me

Comment: Значения древних слов не совпадают с привычными вам понятиями сейчас. Впрочем, я не собираюсь пускаться в прения по этому поводу. Для меня "обобщенного лексического значения "более, чем достаточно. Тем более, я написала, как это можно толковать. "В направлении какого состояния "стремление к какому-то состоянию.

Answer (score 1):

Preposition + adjective in oblique case (without a noun the latter would define) is and has always been a productive pattern of adverb formation in Russian.

Some cases, genders and adjective forms, though, have been more productive in past than now and vice versa.

Here are some of those patterns:

- Short gen. m.: *издалека, слева, сполна*
- Short dat. m.: *понемногу, помалу*
- Full dat. m.: *по-прежнему, по-новому*
- Short acc. m.: *влево, вообще, наголо, подавно*
- Full acc. f.: *впустую, одесную, зачастую*
- Full acc. m. pl.: *впервые*
- Short instr. m.: *по-русски, по-немецки*
- Short loc. m.: *наготове, налегке, вскоре*

As you can see, there are no words "omitted" here: the case and the gender are just repurposed to convey some subtleties in meaning.

Some of those patterns have since stopped being productive. *Впервые*, *вскоре* etc. are fossilized forms, you can't produce new adverbs like those in modern Russian.

Others, like full acc. f. you're asking about, are relatively new. Except for Church Slavonic *одесную* and *ошую*, they are virtually non-existent in medieval and even XVIII texts, but then people picked them up and started using them.

I don't know why did this particular form gain such traction, but you can see a surge in its usage around 1850's, while neither of Lomonosov's, Vostokov's or Gretch's grammars even mention those forms.

Comment: It's most likely just a substantivized adjective, but in the feminine, so as to make it less abstract. Возможное--that which is possible, the possible, старое--the old, that with is old. So впустую is just— as an empty "thing", the empty, in an empty (way).

Comment: i guess it's possible that before XVIII they belonged primarily to colloquial language which is the reason for their absence in the records